# Conditionally execute a command at file load in emacs 24

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking to automate my development and I would like emacs to execute a few commands automatically when I load any file called "project.clj"

Specifically I'd like it to check the open buffers, and if there isn't a buffer called "swank" execute the clojure-jack-in command as if it came from the "project.clj" buffer,

and then I'd like it to run shell and speedbar as well, but I imagine once I figure out how to do the above, those will be easy.

I am a complete elisp noob, but I'm familiar with lisp in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(defun my-project-hook (filename)
  (when (string= (file-name-nondirectory filename) "project.clj")
    (do-stuff)))

(add-hook 'after-load-functions 'my-project-hook)
```

Comment: That works, here's what I used:

`(defun clojure-open ()
  (if (string= (file-name-nondirectory filename) "project.clj")
      (if (not (member "*swank*" (mapcar (function buffer-name) (buffer-list))))
          (clojure-jack-in))))`

Comment: A bit simpler on the inside would be `(unless (get-buffer "*swank*") (clojure-jack-in))`.  BTW, if this answer is working please accept it :)